# Using graphene-django, is it possible to define a circular relationship between two nodes?

Tags: django, graphql, django-filter, graphene-python

Using the following contrived example:

```
from django.db import models
from django_filters import FilterSet, OrderingFilter
from graphene import ObjectType, Schema, relay
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphene_django.filter import DjangoFilterConnectionField

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredient', related_name='recipes')

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class RecipeFilter(FilterSet):

    order_by = OrderingFilter(fields=[('name', 'name')])

    class Meta:
        fields = {'name': ['icontains']}
        model = Recipe

class IngredientFilter(FilterSet):

    order_by = OrderingFilter(fields=[('name', 'name')])

    class Meta:
        fields = {'name': ['icontains']}
        model = Ingredient

class RecipeNode(DjangoObjectType):

    ingredients = DjangoFilterConnectionField(IngredientNode, filterset_class=IngredientFilter)

    class Meta:
        interfaces = [relay.Node]
        model = Recipe
        only_fields = ['name']

class IngredientNode(DjangoObjectType):

    recipes = DjangoFilterConnectionField(RecipeNode, filterset_class=RecipeFilter)

    class Meta:
        interfaces = [relay.Node]
        model = Ingredient
        only_fields = ['name']

class Queries(ObjectType):

    all_recipes = DjangoFilterConnectionField(RecipeNode, filterset_class=RecipeFilter)
    all_ingredients = DjangoFilterConnectionField(IngredientNode, filterset_class=IngredientFilter)

schema = Schema(query=Queries)
```

How can I define the circular relationship between `RecipeNode` and `IngredientNode` such that I can run the following GraphQL query:

```
{
  allRecipes(name_Icontains: "gg") {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        ingredients(name_Icontains: "gg") {
          edges {
            node {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  allIngredients(name_Icontains: "gg") {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        recipes(name_Icontains: "gg") {
          edges {
            node {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As it stands, I cannot reference `IngredientNode` from `RecipeNode` since it is not yet defined.  If I attempt to use a lambda as I've seen recommended elsewhere, I receive `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_meta'`.

```
class IngredientNode(DjangoObjectType):

    recipes = DjangoFilterConnectionField(lambda: RecipeNode, filterset_class=RecipeFilter)

    class Meta:
        interfaces = [relay.Node]
        model = Ingredient
        only_fields = ['name']
```

If I attempt to set the attribute after the fact, I am unable to query for `ingredients` from within a recipe.  There is no error, Graphiql just behaves as though `ingredients` was never defined.

```
class RecipeNode(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        interfaces = [relay.Node]
        model = Recipe
        only_fields = ['name']

class IngredientNode(DjangoObjectType):

    recipes = DjangoFilterConnectionField(RecipeNode, filterset_class=RecipeFilter)

    class Meta:
        interfaces = [relay.Node]
        model = Ingredient
        only_fields = ['name']

RecipeNode.ingredients = DjangoFilterConnectionField(IngredientNode, filterset_class=IngredientFilter)
```

I have to think there's a simple solution to this that I'm just not seeing.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Django 1.8.17, django-filter 0.15.3, graphene-django 1.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity, the way we worked around this issue was to redefine the DjangoFilterConnectionField such that the filterset_class argument is required and we removed code that referenced the node's Meta attributes.  The down side is that we can no longer take advantage of the filter_fields shortcut.  For us, this is not an issue since we have been using FilterSets from the start.

The entire final solution/workaround:

```
from django.db import models
from django_filters import FilterSet, OrderingFilter
from functools import partial
from graphene import ObjectType, Schema, relay
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType, DjangoConnectionField
from graphene_django.filter.utils import get_filtering_args_from_filterset, get_filterset_class

class DjangoFilterConnectionField(DjangoConnectionField):

    def __init__(self, type, filterset_class, *args, **kwargs):

        self.filterset_class = get_filterset_class(filterset_class)
        self.filtering_args = get_filtering_args_from_filterset(self.filterset_class, type)
        kwargs.setdefault('args', {})
        kwargs['args'].update(self.filtering_args)
        super(DjangoFilterConnectionField, self).__init__(type, *args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def connection_resolver(resolver, connection, default_manager, filterset_class, filtering_args,
                            root, args, context, info):
        filter_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in args.items() if k in filtering_args}
        qs = default_manager.get_queryset()
        qs = filterset_class(data=filter_kwargs, queryset=qs).qs
        return DjangoConnectionField.connection_resolver(resolver, connection, qs, root, args, context, info)

    def get_resolver(self, parent_resolver):
        return partial(self.connection_resolver, parent_resolver, self.type, self.get_manager(),
                       self.filterset_class, self.filtering_args)

class Recipe(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredient', related_name='recipes')

class Ingredient(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class RecipeFilter(FilterSet):

    order_by = OrderingFilter(fields=[('name', 'name')])

    class Meta:
        fields = {'name': ['icontains']}
        model = Recipe

class IngredientFilter(FilterSet):

    order_by = OrderingFilter(fields=[('name', 'name')])

    class Meta:
        fields = {'name': ['icontains']}
        model = Ingredient

class RecipeNode(DjangoObjectType):

    ingredients = DjangoFilterConnectionField(lambda: IngredientNode, filterset_class=IngredientFilter)

    class Meta:
        interfaces = [relay.Node]
        model = Recipe
        only_fields = ['name']

class IngredientNode(DjangoObjectType):

    recipes = DjangoFilterConnectionField(RecipeNode, filterset_class=RecipeFilter)

    class Meta:
        interfaces = [relay.Node]
        model = Ingredient
        only_fields = ['name']

class Queries(ObjectType):

    all_recipes = DjangoFilterConnectionField(RecipeNode, filterset_class=RecipeFilter)
    all_ingredients = DjangoFilterConnectionField(IngredientNode, filterset_class=IngredientFilter)

schema = Schema(query=Queries)
```

Redefining DjangoFilterConnectionField in this way allows us to use a lambda to reference nodes that have not yet been defined.